# How do you insert a result of SELECT query into a table?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which consists of multiple columns with one empty column, "Title".

I use this query to get the salutation of a column (Name). Sample value of this Name column is,

```
McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J
```

I can use this Select query to get the Mr. in the value,

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING("Name" from '\w+\.') AS Title_temp
FROM titanic;
```

How do I insert the Title_temp column result of the query into my table, titanic?
I've tried multiple SQL statements but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Take a look at *Examples* section here [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html).

Comment: Do you only want to do this for `"McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J"` or every record? What were the SQL statements you tried?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to `update` the `Title` column in `titanic` with the result of `select substring ("Name" from '\w+\.') from titanic`? Similar to `update titanic set Title = (your_subquery);`?  If not, I'm not understanding where you want to put `"Mr."`, please clarify. If only for `"McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J"`, then add a `where` clause to limit it to him.

Comment: Title_temp column has all the salutations (e.g. Dr. , Mr. , Miss. , Ms. etc.) for every row in the Name column. I just need the Title_temp column values to be inserted into the Title column inside the titanic table. @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Something similar should work, e.g. `update titanic set Title = (select substring("Name" from '\w+\.') from titanic);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to "insert" data into a column, but in SQL that's an UPDATE:

```
UPDATE titanic SET
title = SUBSTRING(name from '\w+\.')
```

---

If you get an error about "missing WHERE clause", add `WHERE 1 = 1` (ie true for all rows) to the query.

Comment: Works like a charm. I just need to edit it like the ones from @DavidC.Rankin's answer. Thanks!

Comment: The masters always have shorter and more efficient ways to skin the same cat `:)`